# Java Swing JTabbedPane add JPanel to tab then modify it

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I want to create a JTabbedPane, add a JPanel to everyone and then add something to the JPanel:

```
private void initTabbedPane(JTabbedPane tp)
{
    System.out.println("FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterface::initTabbedPane()");

    // Init Tab-Names
    Vector<String> tabNames = new Vector<String>();
    tabNames.addElement("Startseite");
    tabNames.addElement("Konfiguration");
    tabNames.addElement("Hilfe");

    // Init Tabs
    tp = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel tmpPanel;
    for(int i = 0; i < tabNames.size(); i++)
    {
        tmpPanel = new JPanel();
        tp.addTab(tabNames.elementAt(i), tmpPanel);
    }
    tp.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 11));
    initPanelsInTabbedPane(tp);
    this.getContentPane().add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private void initPanelsInTabbedPane(JTabbedPane tp)
{
    System.out.println("FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterface::initPanelsInTabbedPane()");

    tp.getComponentAt(0).add(new JButton("HELLOSTUPIDJAVAIHATEU"));
}
```

Well it says: 
incompatible types
found   : java.awt.Component
required: javax.swing.JPanel
        JPanel p = tp.getComponentAt(0);

But my book says that with, Component getComponentAt(int index), i can access it's content and i remember that JButton is a Component right? So wth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at Javadoc, you'll see that, indeed, [`JTabbedPane#getComponentAt(index)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getComponentAt%28int%29) returns a `Component`. However, if you're sure it's a `JPanel` (which is more or less the case when accessing tabs of a `JTabbedPane`), you can always cast it :

```
((JPanel) tp.getComponentAt(0)).add(new JButton("come on, Java is nice enough, no ?"));
```

Or, even better if you know some things about Swing

```
((JCompoonent) tp.getComponentAt(0)).add(new JButton("No, Java and Swing positively rock hard awesome !"));
```

indeed, `JPanel` is a subclass of `JComponent`, which is

- [the root class of all Swing components](http://www.falkhausen.de/en/diagram/html/javax.swing.JComponents.html)
- [an awt Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html)

Comment: hey ty riduidel, i've chosen your second approach, because i think it's more general (i've only jpanels in my tabs. but never mind).

Comment: Yes, second option will always work when using Swing components